# How can I test if my token is expired with IdentityServer4?

Tags: c#, token, identityserver4

I create a token with IdentityServer4 I copy this [example](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Quickstarts/1_ClientCredentials/src) I just modify this

in **IdentityServer** -> **Config**

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()

{
    return new List<Client>
    {
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "client",
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
            ClientSecrets =
            {
                new Secret("secret".Sha256())
            },
            AllowedScopes = { "TRACEITLMAPI" },
            AccessTokenLifetime = 10,
            IdentityTokenLifetime = 10 

        }
    };
}
```

I wanted to test when my token will be expired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An *access token* is a self-contained package that contains [three parts](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-anatomy-of-a-json-web-token):

- header
- payload
- signature

The information is in the payload, while the signature ensures the receiver that the payload has not been altered.

Taking the [terminology](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/intro/terminology.html) from the documentation into account:

The *resource* has the information that needs to be protected. The *client* is the process that wants to *access the resource* and *IdentityServer* is the *issuer* of the access token that the client can use to access the resource.

The token is created by the IdentityServer and the client sends it along with the request in the header to the resource. *So it's the resource that needs to validate the token.* Being self-contained, means that the resource doesn't have to contact the issuer and can fully trust the token *after validation*. Luckily, middleware takes care of that, so you don't have to write code for that.

The token should be *short-lived*, so it's rather seconds, minutes perhaps hours than days. Being short-lived means that the *client* may want to read the token as well. Not necessarily to validate it, but at least to check whether it's not expired. Because it may have to request a new token.

Now to answer your question, the *client* can read the token and validate it as follows:

```
// using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;

var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var jwtSecurityToken = tokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);

if (jwtSecurityToken.ValidTo < DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(10))
    Console.WriteLine("Expired");
```

Please note that this is local validation in the client. This doesn't mean the token isn't accepted by the resource.

The reason is that there's a configurable tolerance level of accepting the token (clock skew). I believe this is by default five minutes. So while the client may have determined that the token is expired, the resource may still accept it if it's within tolerable range.

But this is not something you can count on. So it's better to refresh the token or request a new token (depending on the flow) when the token is (almost) expired.

Some remarks, since the token can't be altered and there's no need for the resource to contact the issuer, there is no way to revoke the token. Therefor it's necessary to set an expiration time. Please note that a new token doesn't invalidate or revoke other (previous, older) tokens. A Jwt always remains valid until it expires.

And about the statement in your answer, this has nothing to do with the validity of the token. This simply prints a string value:

```
Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.AccessToken);
```

Where `tokenResponse` is the result of the request (`RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync`) and `AccessToken` is a property in the response object.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the token in question is a JWT then the expiry time is contained within the token itself as the `exp` claim in Unix epoch format. Check out https://jwt.io - it has a useful token visualisation tool on the front page.

If you want to test it against an API that has been configured to accept your access tokens then bear in mind that there's usually a significant (i.e. in the order of minutes) clock skew allowance so even if your token has expired according to an accurate clock the API will continue to accept it. This is by design and the level of clock skew allowed should be configurable.